# Could Emacs fontify elisp string constants?

Tags: emacs, elisp

## The Dilemma: readability or maintainability?

Let's look at the following function.
It doesn't really matter what it does, the important part is that
it's using twice the string `"(let\\*?[ \t]*"`:

```
(defun setq-expression-or-sexp ()
  "Return the smallest list that contains point.
If inside VARLIST part of `let' form,
return the corresponding `setq' expression."
  (interactive)
  (ignore-errors
    (save-excursion
      (up-list)
      (let ((sexp (preceding-sexp)))
        (backward-list 1)
        (cond
         ((looking-back "(let\\*?[ \t]*")
          (cons 'setq
                (if (= (length sexp) 1)
                    (car sexp)
                  (cl-mapcan
                   (lambda (x) (unless (listp x) (list x nil)))
                   sexp))))
         ((progn
            (up-list)
            (backward-list 1)
            (looking-back "(let\\*?[ \t]*"))
          (cons 'setq sexp))
         (t
          sexp))))))
```

Since it's a headache having to update the string in two (or more) locations,
I'd have to `defconst` it like so:

```
(defconst regex-let-form "(let\\*?[ \t]*")
```

Although the code became more maintainable, it became less readable as well,
because it's hard to see at a glance what `regex-let-form` really is:

```
(defun setq-expression-or-sexp ()
  "Return the smallest list that contains point.
If inside VARLIST part of `let' form,
return the corresponding `setq' expression."
  (interactive)
  (ignore-errors
    (save-excursion
      (up-list)
      (let ((sexp (preceding-sexp)))
        (backward-list 1)
        (cond
         ((looking-back regex-let-form)
          (cons 'setq
                (if (= (length sexp) 1)
                    (car sexp)
                  (cl-mapcan
                   (lambda (x) (unless (listp x) (list x nil)))
                   sexp))))
         ((progn
            (up-list)
            (backward-list 1)
            (looking-back regex-let-form))
          (cons 'setq sexp))
         (t
          sexp))))))
```

## The idea: why not both?

Since it's a constant anyway, why not `font-lock` it
and make `regex-let-form` appear as if it's `"(let\\*?[ \t]*"`?
It's a feasable job, since:

1. It's possible to font-lock identifiers like so: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PrettyLambda,
   or even so: [rainbow-mode](http://julien.danjou.info/projects/emacs-packages).
2. And it's possible to font-lock constants. It's already done for c++-mode,
   but not yet for emacs-lisp-mode, as far as I know.

Then it remains only to connect the two. Unfortunately, I don't know
enough of `font-lock` innards to do it, but maybe someone else does?
Or is there already a package that does this?

Answer (score 1):

Tweaking the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289329/),
I've solved the problem:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 
 'emacs-lisp-mode
 '((fl-string-constant . 'font-lock-constant-face)) 'append)

(defun fl-string-constant (_limit)
  (while (not 
          (ignore-errors
            (save-excursion
              (skip-chars-forward "'")
              (let ((opoint (point))
                    (obj (read (current-buffer)))
                    obj-val)
                (and (symbolp obj)
                     (risky-local-variable-p obj)
                     (special-variable-p obj)
                     (stringp (setq obj-val (eval obj)))
                     (progn
                       (put-text-property 
                        (1- (point)) (point) 'display
                        (format "%c\"%s\"" (char-before) obj-val))
                       (set-match-data (list opoint (point))) 
                       t))))))
    (if (looking-at "\\(\\sw\\|\\s_\\)")
        (forward-sexp 1)
      (forward-char 1)))
  t)
```

This displays the value of a string constant right after the constant name.
It works quite nicely with fontified string constants as well.
Speed is a bit of an issue - suggestions to improve are welcome.

Also, I couldn't find anything better than `risky-local-variable-p` to determine
that it's a constant. The doc says that `defconst` marks the variable
as special and risky, but nothing else.

Comment: @Drew, I've used your code from another answer. Thanks. Could you suggest how to speed up the function?

Comment: Haven't really looked at it, but my other answer should do what you want. In the above code, you are reading each quoted Lisp object etc. If you just check first whether you are looking at a symbol then you don't need to do read each object, or even any objects -- just check the symbol value. But as I say, I haven't really studied your code etc. Try [`hl-defined.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/hl-defined.el) -- I think it will do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

[`hl-defined.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/hl-defined.el) (updated today, 2013-10-20) can highlight constant Emacs-Lisp symbols as such, that is, variables whose current value is the symbol itself.  If your `defconst` has been evaluated then this will do what you are requesting.

Comment: It just changes the face, right? Doesn't substitute the values of constants?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I've reverted the changes I made to `hl-defined.el` today. They just made it possible to highlight *self-evaluating* constants, which is not useful. If it weren't for [Emacs bug #15666](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=15666) then it would be easy to handle constants defined using `defconst`. Alas, that regression means that one can no longer advise special forms. I will delete this answer, if you reply here that you have seen this retraction comment.

Comment: Too bad. Keep the link - more motivation to fix the bug:)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work (source: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PrettyLambda):

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'emacs-lisp-mode
  `(("\\<\\(regex-let-form\\)\\>" (0 (prog1 nil
                                       (compose-region (match-beginning 1)
                                                       (match-end 1)
                                                       "\"(let\\\\*?[ \\t]*\""))))))
```

Although I think adding `regex-let-form` into the existing `let` block would be a cleaner solution:

```
(let ((sexp (preceding-sexp))
      (regex-let-form "(let\\*?[ \t]*"))
    ...
```

Comment: I tried it and it gave me a weird unicode char instead of regex-let-form.

Comment: It might be a version issue. I'm using v24.2.

Comment: I don't think it's a weird unicode character. More likely just every character in that string, stacked on top of each other.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps your example is not indicative of the real problem, and you really do want to do some display replacement or font-locking, as you say.

But I will answer wrt your example and the problem as posed, regarding maintainability vs readability: Just `let`-bind your regexp.  The binding, unlike a `defconst` will be nearby and clearly related to the occurrences of the bound variable.

This is typically what people do. Again, you might have had another use case in mind --- I am responding only to the problem as posed narrowly.

Comment: `let`-bind, is the obvious answer, and it's obviously deficient.
The regex can be used across functions, also it's a constant
which `let` doesn't reflect. Finally and most importantly,
the readability is lost. When I read a line with `looking-back`,
I really want to see what I'm looking back at /there/, and not
10 lines higher.