# How to highlight all the function's name in Emacs' lisp-mode?

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp, syntax-highlighting, font-lock

How to highlight all the function's name in Emacs' lisp-mode? I want them bolded.

In other words, all the words from `(` to the first `space`. **Don't care** exceptions like `(a . b)`

Just like GitHub:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this:

```
(defface font-lock-func-face 
    '((nil (:foreground "#7F0055" :weight bold))
      (t (:bold t :italic t)))
  "Font Lock mode face used for function calls."
  :group 'font-lock-highlighting-faces)

(font-lock-add-keywords 
 'emacs-lisp-mode
 '(("(\\s-*\\(\\_<\\(?:\\sw\\|\\s_\\)+\\)\\_>"
    1 'font-lock-func-face)))
```

A funny thing: this messes up with `let` bindings, just like Github.
But that's what you asked for, right:)?

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand that `\\(...\\)` is the point. But I want to know what is that "1" meaning?

Comment: 1 means `the first captured group`, 2 would mean the second captured group, if there was one. 0 means the whole match

Comment: Better: Please remove the variable, and just leave the `defface`.  Face variables are obsolete.  You may probably want to use the built-in `font-lock-function-name-face` instead. The regexp fails to catch some fairly common function names (i.e. `string=`, `<=`, `+`, or `foo/bar`).  `"(\\s-*\\(\\_<\\(?:\\sw\\|\\s_\\)+\\)\\_>"` gives a more complete coverage.

Comment: This will not override already highlighted text: `(font-lock-add-keywords
 'lisp-mode
 '(("(\\s-*\\(\\_<\\(?:\\sw\\|\\s_\\)+\\)\\_>"
    1 'font-lock-func-face keep))
 t)`

Answer (score 6):

The code below highlights the names of known Emacs-Lisp functions.

Be aware that it does so even if some occurrence of a given function name does not represent the function.  For example, the name might be used as a variable name.  Not a big problem in practice, but good to know.

```
;; `setq' is a variable here, but it is highlighted anyway.
(let ((setq  (foobar)))...)
```

To turn on the highlighting automatically in Emacs-Lisp mode, do this:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'emacs-lisp-mode
                        '((my-fl . 'font-lock-constant-face)) ; Or whatever face you want.                            'APPEND)

(defun my-fl (_limit)
  (let ((opoint  (point))
        (found   nil))
    (with-syntax-table emacs-lisp-mode-syntax-table
      (while (not found)
        (cond ((condition-case ()
                   (save-excursion
                     (skip-chars-forward "'")
                     (setq opoint  (point))
                     (let ((obj  (read (current-buffer))))
                       (and (symbolp obj)  (fboundp obj)
                            (progn (set-match-data (list opoint (point))) t))))
                 (error nil))
               (forward-sexp 1)
               (setq opoint  (point)
                     found   t))
              (t
               (if (looking-at "\\(\\sw\\|\\s_\\)")
                   (forward-sexp 1)
                 (forward-char 1)))))
      found)))
```

Note: If you want to see the effect of only this highlighting, then first do this in an Emacs-Lisp mode buffer, to get rid of other Emacs-Lisp font-lock highlighting:

```
M-: (setq font-lock-keywords  ()) RET
```

***UPDATE ---***

I created a minor-mode command and library for this:

- Code: [`hl-defined.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/hl-defined.el)
- [`Description`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightLispFunctions)

It lets you highlight defined Emacs-Lisp symbols: functions and variables, only functions, or only variables.  Alternatively you can highlight only symbols ***not*** known to be defined.

Comment: I may have misread the code, but can't the whole `condition-case` be replaced with a `(thing-at-point 'symbol)`?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. ;-)  See `function-called-at-point`, for instance.